# Anyone know the name of this type of switch?

Tags: switches, components

Does anyone know the name of the internal switch (circled in red) in this assembly? It is a latching switch, so much to close and then push again to open. I've been Googling and hunting for about 2 hours and clearly not typing in the correct name and I just keep finding panel switches or the complete plastic assembly, which I don't need.[image: Foot switch assembly]

UPDATE: Just managed to find an application note on switches, the type of switch I am after is a push button alternate switch it seems. Still can't seem to find the type pictured though.

Comment: Is that a picture from an ebay.co.uk search for "push button light switch"? The other search results include the item you're after. You may need to remove the screw-on part used for panel mounting them. The only problem I see is finding out the length of the threaded portion.

Comment: Genius, I had been searching for "Lamp floor switch" which doesn't bring them up - your right though! That's exactly what I am after - I swear half of this work is just a text adventure game looking for the right words!

Comment: You are unlikely to find the internal switch as it is probably made by or for the people who make the complete unit. Buy another complete unit and spend the Google time saved on something better!

Comment: Well, I'll probably buy 10K of them next winter 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks just like a bed-lamp switch except without the phosphorescent plunger, (and with the panel-mount bezel-nut removed) you could probably substitute a bed-lamp switch without any problems.

https://www.jaycar.com.au/240v-2a-bed-lamp-style-pushbutton-switch-spst/p/SP0735

These things were once common as dirt, you can probably still get them from a local electical parts supplier

The term "desk lamp switch" also seems to be applied to this device.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully there are some letters and/or numbers on the existing switch. Look closely for a manufacturer's logo; may have to use a magnifying lens. Match that up with [the manufacturer](https://www.elnec.com/en/support/ic-logos/?method=logo). Punch those words into Google or Octopart.com.

If there are no identifying marks, then the switch is custom-made, and the only source is the Original Equipment Manufacturer (OEM.)